# Get без Ajax. Возможен ли?

Tags: php, get

Есть строка адреса:
`http://site/page.php?full_content=8`

Получаемая через:

```
<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='get'>
  <a href='javascript:window.history.pushState(\"1\", \"Title\", \"?full_content=".$sufix."\");' onclick='showBlock_".$sufix."()'>
  <span class='link_more' onClick='dark_view_2(\"on\");'>Подробнее...</span>
  </a>
  </form>
```

И должна открывать:

```
$index_out=$_GET['full_content'];
...
  print $content_array[$index_out];
```

Возможна ли реализация того, чтобы с url бралась переменная, передавалась в `showBlock_".$sufix."()`
И открывался объект? Без применения стороннего jQuery, ну и, возможно, без Ajax, допустим на голом JavaScript+php.
А то у меня он открывается и тут же закрывается, так как страница "переходит\обновляется" на вновь сделанный url, допустим: `http://site/page.php?full_content=[новое значение]`

[Тут исходный, практически рабочий код (полная версия)](http://viper-7.com/tcYQuy#)
*(На локалке будет работать лучше, так как get.)*

Comment: если на своем де домене `location.href` возвращает полностью `url`

Answer (score 1):

```
function getUrlParameters() {
    var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
    return prmstr != null && prmstr != "" ? toObject(prmstr) : {};
}

function toObject( prmstr ) {
    var params = {};
    var prmarr = prmstr.split("&");
    for ( var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
        var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
        params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
    }
    return params;
}

console.log(getUrlParameters());
```

Как вариант - воспользоваться библиотекой [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html#accessors-search), написанной на нативном js.

```
URI().search(true);
```

Comment: Что-то не получается у меня. Вот мое "произведение". Может полный код больше даст информации: http://viper-7.com/qSh7xl